# SQLAlchemy Core deduplication of common columns between tables

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have the following three tables that I want to create:

```
a = db.Table(
    'a', metadata,
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('created', server_default=func.now()),
    db.Column('updated', server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp()),

    db.Column('unique_to_a', db.INTEGER, nullable=True)
)

b = db.Table(
    'b', metadata,
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('created', server_default=func.now()),
    db.Column('updated', server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp()),

    db.Column('unique_to_b', db.INTEGER, nullable=True)
)

c = db.Table(
    'c', metadata,
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('created', server_default=func.now()),
    db.Column('updated', server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp()),


    db.Column('a_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a.id'), index=True, nullable=True),
    db.Column('unique_to_c', db.INTEGER, nullable=True)
)
```

There are common columns between all three (`id`, `created`, and `updated`), as well as columns unique to each.

**Is there an easy way to create a base table that can have all the shared columns?**

e.g. something like

```
base_table = db.Table(
    'base', metadata,
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('created', server_default=func.now()),
    db.Column('updated', server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp()),
)

a = db.Table(
    'a', metadata,
    base_table,

    db.Column('unique_to_a', db.INTEGER, nullable=True)
)
```

We would prefer to do this all within SQLAlchemy Core (i.e. not use the ORM).

We have used `deepcopy` (`from copy import deepcopy`) before, but we figured there has to be a better way to share columns between tables.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a busy week, so I haven't had a chance to test it. Will try that tomorrow!

Comment: Seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to my knowledge, `Table` cannot inherit, but `declarative` models can, you could leverage on it to create table object:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class BaseColumn(object):
    id = Column('id', Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    created = Column('created', server_default=func.now())
    updated = Column('updated', server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp())

class A(Base, BaseColumn):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    a_column = Column('unique_to_a', INTEGER, nullable=True)


print `A.__table__`
```

output:

`Table('a', MetaData(bind=Engine(sqlite://)), Column('id', Integer(), table=<a>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('created', NullType(), table=<a>, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x105bce490; now>, for_update=False)), Column('updated', NullType(), table=<a>, onupdate=ColumnDefault(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.current_timestamp at 0x105bce750; current_timestamp>), server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x105bce610; now>, for_update=False)), Column('unique_to_a', INTEGER(), table=<a>), schema=None)`

Answer (score 4):

A workaround for anyone using [asyncpgsa](https://github.com/CanopyTax/asyncpgsa) with sqlalchemy core without using `deepcopy`:

```
def base_columns():
    return {
        Column('created_at',
               DateTime(timezone=True),
               server_default=func.clock_timestamp()),
        Column('modified_at',
               DateTime(timezone=True),
               server_default=func.clock_timestamp(),
               onupdate=func.clock_timestamp()),
    }

company_tbl = Table(
    'company', metadata,
    Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', Text, nullable=False, unique=True),
    *base_columns(),
)
```

Comment: Should it return Tuple rather than Set? Maybe just `return (Column(...), Column(...))`